# First item of the listView is not loaded full data from the custom adapter's layout file but the rest are working just fine

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, custom-adapter

The first item of the listView does not display as it is supposed to like the rest two, but when clicked on the first item and then directed to the next page the whole content is display.

Screenshot

[image]

> This is the activity where list is to be loaded

```
public class FacultyViewNoticeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private ListView listView;
private DatabaseReference reference;
private List<Notice> noticesList;
private FacultyViewNoticeAdapter assAdapter;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_faculty_view_notice);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_FacultyViewNoticeActivity);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    declarations();
    loadNoticeList();

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

private void declarations() {
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewNotice_FacultyViewNoticeActivity);
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    noticesList = new ArrayList<>();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(FacultyViewNoticeActivity.this);
}

private void loadNoticeList() {
    pDialog.setTitle("Searching...");
    pDialog.show();
    reference.child("notice").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            noticesList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot ps : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Notice n = ps.getValue(Notice.class);
                Log.i("CollegeDiary", "Notice = " + n.getNotice() + "\nTitle = " + n.getTitle());
                noticesList.add(n);
            }
            assAdapter = new FacultyViewNoticeAdapter(FacultyViewNoticeActivity.this, noticesList);
            listView.setAdapter(assAdapter);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    });
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    Notice a = noticesList.get(i);
    Intent intent = new Intent(FacultyViewNoticeActivity.this, FacultyViewNoticeDetailsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Data", a);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

> activity_faculty_view_notice.xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.collegecoder.collegediary.activity.FacultyViewNoticeActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_FacultyViewNoticeActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewNotice_FacultyViewNoticeActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

> This is the adapter for it

```
public class FacultyViewNoticeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
private Activity context;
private List<Notice> noticeList;
private static int x = 0;

public FacultyViewNoticeAdapter(Activity context, List<Notice> noticeList) {
    super(context, R.layout.layout_view_notices, noticeList);
    this.context = context;
    this.noticeList = noticeList;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_view_notices, parent, false);

    TextView title = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.title_layout_view_notices);
    TextView date = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.date_layout_view_notices);
    TextView notice = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.notice_layout_view_notices);

    Notice noticeUpload = noticeList.get(position);

    if (noticeUpload != null) {
        Log.i("CollegeDiary", String.valueOf(x));
        title.setText(noticeUpload.getTitle());
        notice.setText(noticeUpload.getNotice());
        date.setText(noticeUpload.getD() + "-" + noticeUpload.getM() + "-" + noticeUpload.getY());
        Log.i("CollegeDiary", "ADAPTER = " + title.getText().toString() + "\n" + notice.getText().toString() + "\n" + date.getText().toString());
        x++;
    } else {
        Log.i("CollegeDiary", "null");
    }
    return listViewItem;
}
```

}

> layout_view_notices.xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_layout_view_notices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="totle"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date_layout_view_notices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Date" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/notice_layout_view_notices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="description"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first item is ok. He just behind actionBar

try change main

> LinearLayout

to

> RelativeLayout

to appBarLayout add id field 
and to listview add

```
android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayoutId"
```

after all should be fine.

or add to listview

> topMargin = ?attr/actionBarSize"

Comment: peter both components are in linear layout so why it will happen i am bit confused can you explain

Comment: im not sure, im not using AppBarLayout. But i think problem in line AppBarOverlay

Comment: One more thing is now after switching back from relativelayout to linearlayout and a "Clean Project" task, now it just works fine with the LinearLayout too..